# How to select leaf node using jQuery :contains selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get leaf elements containing specific text, and I used `:contains` selector. However, this selector selects includes every parent nodes too. Here is my example.

```
<div id='parent1'>
    <p id='target1'>Red balloon</p>
    <div id='target2'>Blue balloon</div>
</div>
<div id='parent2'>
    <span id='target3'>Brown balloon</span>
</div>
```

In this case, I just want to get elements containing text *balloon*. I expected to get 3 elements(`target1`, `target2`, `target3`) by `$(":contains('balloon')")`, but it returns every nodes including parent nodes of *targets*. (e.g. `html`, `body`, and every parent `div`)

How can I select only *targets*?

**p.s** Above HTML is only example. HTML can be vary, so the answer should be generic.

Comment: please include all relevant code

Comment: In fact, HTML cannot be editable, I should load various external HTML in `iframe` and I have to select elements containing user input keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use `indexOf("balloon") > -1` to find id the word `balloon` is found

```js
var arr = $("div").children().map(function(){

if($(this).text().indexOf("balloon") > -1 )
return $(this).attr("id")
}).get();

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent1'>
    <p id='target1'>Red balloon</p>
    <div id='target2'>Blue balloon</div>
</div>
<div id='parent2'>
    <span id='target3'>Brown balloon</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Like the answer guradio, may i ask would there be a problem with this solution ? https://jsfiddle.net/tz0ujs10/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i dont see any problem on it mate

Comment: Okay cheers for your time, could not make my mind about my solution for the problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

The solution below, look for all elements containing the word and clone these elements, This way we can be sure only to get "correct" amount of elements

Just remove `.length` and you have access to the elements.

```js
var s = $(":contains('balloon')").not("script").filter(function() {
    return (
    $(this).clone() //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove() //remove all the children
    .end() //again go back to selected element
    .filter(":contains('balloon')").length > 0)
}).length;

console.log(s)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent1'>
  <p id='target1'>Red balloon</p>
  <div id='target2'>Blue balloon</div>
</div>
<div id='parent2'>
  <span id='target3'>Brown balloon</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Aigori No problem, happy to help